# retrieve environment values with get(ls()) in R

Tags: r, environment-variables

I wanted to write a simple function in R that parses through the variables in `ls()` and takes their value. however, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since when I run the following code:

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
l <- c("a", "b")
get_val <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    print(paste(x[i]))
    if(x[i] %in% ls()){
      print(paste(x[i], "value is", get(ls()[which(ls() %in% x[i])])))
    }
  }
}

get_val(l)
```

this returns only

```
> get_val(l)
[1] "a"
[1] "b"
```

while if I run only the for loop inside the function as:

```
  for(i in 1:length(l)){
    print(paste(l[i]))
    if(l[i] %in% ls()){
      print(paste(l[i], "value is", get(ls()[which(ls() %in% l[i])])))
    }
  }
```

I get correctly

```
[1] "a"
[1] "a value is 1"
[1] "b"
[1] "b value is 2"
```

I'm not really sure why that is, any input would be awesome, thanks :)

Comment: It's because `ls()` is returning the objects in the local environment of your function. Read up on the various ways to specify the environment in `?ls`.

Comment: ...also note that the Description in `?ls` states this behavior explicitly: "When invoked with no argument inside a function, ls returns the names of the function's local variables"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ls` inside the function looks in the function's environment, not the parent environment.

Try `ls([stuff], envir=.GlobalEnv`

Shameless plug: take a peek at the source for `lstype` and `lssize` in the package `cgwtools` (latest version available at [my github](https://github.com/cellocgw) ).

Answer (score 1):

The current values of "a" and "b" (1 and 2) are indeed retained into the function environment, but not the values names, so when you invoke x[i] %in%  ls(), the name of these values are not found. Yout "if" is not considered

This will work as well as for obvious reasons

```
    l <- c("a", "b")

     get_val <- function(x){
     a <- 1
     b <- 2 
     for(i in 1:length(x)){
          print(paste(x[i]))
          if(x[i] %in% ls() ){
               print(paste(x[i], "value is", get(ls()[which(ls() %in% x[i])])))
          }
     }
}

get_val(l)
```